# Resume completion port notification after they were stopped

Tags: c++, windows, asynchronous, winapi, overlapped-io

In the MSDN doc for the `lpOverlapped` parameter of [GetQueuedCompletionStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986(v=vs.85).aspx) it is said that the application can prevent completion port notification by setting the low-order bit of the `hEvent` member of the `OVERLAPPED` structure. But is it possible to resume the notifications after they were stopped?

I need to use this for monitoring network folders for changes:

When `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` returns `FALSE` and `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED`, I do this (works):

```
di->Overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent( NULL, FALSE, FALSE, di->lpszDirName );
reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t &>(di->Overlapped.hEvent) |= 0x1;
```

And when the network problem was resolved, I tried to do the reverse operation - but it DID NOT work:

```
reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t &>(di->Overlapped.hEvent) &= ~(0x1);
```

(It will be good if the solution be compatible with Windows 7)

Comment: the documentation is very bad and you misunderstand it. *resume completion port notification* is absolute senseless. it can not be suspended or resumed. what is said in msnd at all not related to `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` api, but for some io request - how skip queue packet to port for **this** request. and unclear at all why you try to do (you not show code)

Comment: however from 3 lines of your codfe absolute unclear what is you try todo and how this at all related to `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`

Answer (score 2):

first of all completion port notification can not be "suspended" or "resumed"

> Even if you have passed the function a file handle associated with a
>   completion port and a valid `OVERLAPPED` structure, an application can
>   prevent completion port notification. This is done by specifying a
>   valid event handle for the `hEvent` member of the `OVERLAPPED` structure,
>   and setting its low-order bit. A valid event handle whose low-order
>   bit is set keeps I/O completion from being queued to the completion
>   port.

this mean the next - when we call some win32 I/O api (api which take pointer to `OVERLAPPED` as in/out parameter, such as `ReadFile`, `ReadDirectoryChangesW`, `LockFileEx` etc) and file handle (passed to this api) associated with a completion port - despite this we can prevent completion port notification for **this** call by event handle with low-order bit. this is for only concrete api call and not affect any another api calls. and all this unrelated to `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`

(strictly said we can simply pass `1` in place `hEvent` too. but in this case question - how we get notify about I/O complete, if api return pending status ? yes possible wait and on file handle only, call `GetOverlappedResult`. but this will be correct only in no any another I/O call on this file in concurent)

in any case need understand how this is internally work. all native I/O api have the next signature:

```
NTSTATUS NTAPI SomeIoApi(
                         _In_ HANDLE FileHandle,
                         _In_opt_ HANDLE Event,
                         _In_opt_ PIO_APC_ROUTINE ApcRoutine,
                         _In_opt_ PVOID ApcContext,
                         _Out_ PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, 
                         ...
                         );
```

all have this common 5 parameters at begin. for queue I/O completion as result of this call several conditions must be met. of course `FileHandle` must be associated with some completion port (to this port and can be packet sent). but else one mandatory condition - `ApcContext` must be not zero (`ApcContext != 0`). if this 2 condition met and device return not error status (if [`FILE_SKIP_COMPLETION_PORT_ON_SUCCESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setfilecompletionnotificationmodes) set on file - must be pending status only) - when I/O complete - `ApcContext` pointer will be pushed to port. and then it can be removed by

```
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
NtRemoveIoCompletion(
    _In_ HANDLE IoCompletionHandle,
    _Out_ PVOID *KeyContext,
    _Out_ PVOID *ApcContext,
    _Out_ PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
    _In_opt_ PLARGE_INTEGER Timeout
    );
```

or by it win32 shell `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`.

so solution for not sent packet to port (even is  file handle associated with completion port) - set `ApcContext = 0`. win32 layer do this in next way (pseudo - code):

```
BOOL WINAPI SomeWin32Api(
                         HANDLE FileHandle,
                         LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped,
                         LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine
             )
{

    HANDLE hEvent = lpOverlapped->hEvent;
    PVOID ApcContext = lpOverlapped;

    if ((ULONG_PTR)hEvent & 1)
    {
        reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t&>(hEvent) &= ~1;
        ApcContext = 0;
    }

    NTSTATUS status = SomeIoApi(
        FileHandle, 
        hEvent, 
        lpCompletionRoutine, // not exactly, but by sense
        ApcContext, 
        (PIO_STATUS_BLOCK)lpOverlapped,...);
}
```

it check low-order bit of `hEvent` in `OVERLAPPED` - if it set - pass 0 inplace `ApcContext` otherwise pass `lpOverlapped` (pointer to `OVERLAPPED`) as context ( `ApcContext = lpOverlapped;`)

note that nt layer let pass any `void*` pointer as `ApcContext`. but win32 layer always pass here pointer to `OVERLAPPED` structure or 0. because this and `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` return this pointer back as `_Out_ LPOVERLAPPED *lpOverlapped` (compare with `NtRemoveIoCompletion` - return as `_Out_ PVOID *ApcContext`)

anyway this trick affect only concrete single win32 I/O call, and if you late reset low-order bit in `hEvent`  from overlapped ( `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t &>(di->Overlapped.hEvent) &= ~(0x1);`) this already can not have any effect - the 0 in place `ApcContext` already passed.

also from general view this is rarely when we associate file handle with a completion port, but want not use it in some call. usually this is another api call. for example we can create asynchronous file handle, associate it with a completion port. and use port notifications in call `WriteFile`, but before begin write we can set/remove compression on file via `FSCTL_SET_COMPRESSION`. because file is asynchronous, the `FSCTL_SET_COMPRESSION` also can complete asynchronous, but we can want prevent completion port notification for this ioctl, instead wait inplace (on event) for it complete. for such situation and can be used this trick.

and in most case applications (if this not server with huge count of i/o requests) can instead manual call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`, bind callback to file via `BindIoCompletionCallback` or `CreateThreadpoolIo`. as result system for you create iocp, thread pool which will be listen on this iocp (via `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` or `NtRemoveIoCompletion`) and then call your callback. this is very simplify your src code and logic

---

findings:

- i almost sure (despite not view your code) that you not need at all
  use trick with event low-order bit
- if you use this trick in some I/O request (say `ReadDirectoryChangesW`)
  this affect only this particular request
- you can not change the behaviour by reset low-order bit in event
  handle after request is sent, or by any another way
- you in general not need use `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` and self thread
  pool at all. instead simply call `BindIoCompletionCallback` for file